# Not understanding Spring SessionAttribute and Autowiring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm not a Spring expert and I'm facing a behavior I don't understand...

I have a SessionAttribute "user" in my Controller, that is autowired to my bean User.
When I log in, my User is populated with some values etc.

When I log out, I am expecting that my session attribute "user" would be reset, but it keeps its values.

So where is the problem? Is my log out not working properly? Or is it normal and so, could someone explain me what is happening inside Spring please?

Here is a code Sample to understand my question:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class HomeController
{
    @Autowired
    private User user;

    // Session Attribute
    @ModelAttribute("user")
    public User setSessionAttribute()
    {
        LOGGER.debug("Adding user to session...");
        return user;
    }

    ...
}
```

Edit: logout sample code and user declaration

My User is declared like this:

```
@Component
public class User
{
   ...
}
```

To log out I have a link pointing to /myapp/j_spring_security_logout and I have implemented a logout handler:

```
@Component
public class MyLogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler
{

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {
            //to check if user is in session, but it's not
        Enumeration<String> e = request.getSession().getAttributeNames();

        //some code needed to log out from my custom security manager
            //kill the session (not spring session) and redirect to the specified url
            agent.logout("/myapp/login");

        super.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you log out ? Can you post the code for logout

Comment: Where is your `User` bean declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you've posted `User`

```
@Component
public class User
{
   ...
}
```

you will notice that it is has Singleton scope. The bean autowired here

```
@Autowired
private User user;
```

is that singleton instance. It will always be the same regardless of what Session or request you're processing and regardless of you logging out. So up to now, all your users have been sharing the same `User` instance.

You can change it to have Session scope.

```
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@Component
public class User
{
   ...
}
```

Now each Session will have its own instance to work with.

Comment: I don't well understand what proxymode do, but it works, thank you! I hadn't seen that default scope was singleton reading the doc

Comment: @thibon You're welcome. For Spring to achieve session scope, it needs to wrap your object in a proxy that always gives you a different object depending on your session. There are 2 types of proxies, Java JDK proxies and CGLIB proxies. That attribute specifies which to use. You can read more about it in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler` is not clearing the content of the `session`.

`SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler` only invokes the `handle()` method in `AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler` and it's [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.html#handle%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20org.springframework.security.core.Authentication%29) says:

> Invokes the configured RedirectStrategy with the URL returned by the determineTargetUrl method.
>   The redirect will not be performed if the response has already been committed.

Simplest solution would be to remove this attribute from the `session` by:

```
request.getSession().removeAttribute("user");
```